# Is there any way to cancel executing query and close database in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, postgresql, connection

I am making asp.net app which makes database query measurement. There are two buttons on my webpage start and stop. Start button function connects to PostgreSQL database, then execute 100 queries and then close the connection:

```
Connect();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = Connection;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    cmd.CommandText = queries[i];
    cmd.ExecuteReader().Close();
}
Close();
```

This function usually takes 7 seconds.
When I click to stop button during function execution which function is `Connection.Close()`, I am getting error that there is executing query, so connection cannot be closed. Is there any way how can I cancel executing query and then close connection while there is execution loop?

I tried somehow to cancel query by his pid, but doesn't works (probably bad implementation because query with that pid already done)

Comment: Typically, a `CancellationToken` would be used - see the docs for the methods which support it.  Within the loop, check if cancellation is requested and return early.  Also, it's unknown what these queries are doing, but if they are independent then they could be executed concurrently (or some sub-set) to reduce overall time.  Or possibly, some batch queries instead of sequential queries.

Comment: These queries are only SELECT queries

Answer (score 1):

I think I would "dump" the idea of trying to "cancel" a running query. It's kind of like throwing a stick of dynamite at the server anyway.

The "real" goal here is not really to STOP a running query, but in fact to "nice" and "gentle" stop our query processing loop.

In other words, let's give the server ONLY say a 1/2 second of processing time. It might do 5 query, maybe 10. However, THEN if we decide to stop the query process loop, then the browser will respond at least within about 1/2 second - not much more.

So, better idea is to "stop" the process loop. So, when we hit stop button, maybe 5-10 more queries run - but that's less then 1 second, and we don't care.

So, I suggest we break down this "challenge" to that of

Call the server to start running some queries - but ONLY let it run for say about 1/2 second. Don't care if it only gets 1 query done, or say 10 done.

Then, when that "chunk" is done, we can update the progress. And "bonus" here is we can then track/see/display HOW many queries are done so far!!!

At this point then?

Well, if user hit stop button, then we stop.

However, more queries to run? Then simple keep going!!! (and CONTINUE from +1 last query done).

So, this approach not only removes the "problem" of killing a running query (that stick of dynamite we're trying to throw at the server), but it also means our stop button works well, and we as noted also then get how many queries have been done so far.

So, our server side web method could be this:

(Again, I don't have the 100 queries, but don't matter - air code warning!!).

Server side code:

```
public class MyStatInfo
{
    public int NumQuery = 112;
    public int QueryDone = 0;
}

[WebMethod]
public static MyStatInfo RunQuery(int StartQuery)
{
    MyStatInfo cQueryinfo= new MyStatInfo();

    // run queries untill at "least" 0.5 seocnds has passed.
    double RunTime = 500;   // adjiust a bit up or down
    double sStart = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;

    while (StartQuery <= cQueryinfo.NumQuery)
    {
        // fake query
        //  do query (StartQuery)
        cQueryinfo.QueryDone++;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);  // Fake query delay time

        double sNow  = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (sNow >= RunTime) {
            // return to client
            return cQueryinfo;
        }
        StartQuery++;
    }
    return cQueryinfo;
}
```

So, that routine is to be passed the "starting" query number out of our 112 (or however many). it will start execute of each query - but ONLY until such time wew used up more then 1/2 second of processing.

So, now our client side markup:

2 gauge(s), and 2 buttons (start and stop).

So, markup:

```
<div id="gauge0" style="float:left;margin-left:25px;width:120px"></div>

<div id="gauge1" style="float:left;margin-left:30px;width:120px;"></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server" Text="Start Query Test"
        style="float:left;margin-left:20px" CssClass="btn btn-info"
        OnClientClick="mystart();return false"                        
        />

    <asp:Button ID="cmdStop" runat="server" Text="Stop Query Test"
        style="float:left;margin-left:30px" CssClass="btn btn-danger"
        OnClientClick="mystop();return false"                        
        />
</div>
```

So, 2 buttons + 2 gauge.

And right below above markup, then we simple "keep" calling the server side routine over and over until all done, or stop button press.

```
    <script>
        var gauge0;
        var gauge1;

        var MyTimer;
        var ElapsedMSecs = 0.0
        var StopLoop = false
        var qPtr = 1
        var QueryDone = 0
        var QueryRemain = 0

        function mystart() {

            ElapsedMSecs = 0
            gauge0.refresh(0, 15, 0)
            gauge1.refresh(0, 50, 0)
            qPtr = 1        // query to start at
            qQueryDone = 0  // number of query done so far
            qRemain = 0
            StopLoop = false
            startloop()
        }

        function mystop() {
            StopLoop = true
        }

        function startloop() {

            var ETime = new Date();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GuageTest3.aspx/RunQuery",
                data: JSON.stringify({StartQuery : qPtr}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (MyStats) {
                    var ETime2 = new Date();
                    ElapsedMSecs += (ETime2 - ETime)

                    gauge0.refresh((ElapsedMSecs / 1000))
                    qQueryDone += MyStats.d.QueryDone
                    gauge1.refresh(qQueryDone,MyStats.d.NumQuery, 0)

                    // check for stop button value
                    if (StopLoop)
                         return

                    // more query to run???
                    if ( (MyStats.d.NumQuery - qQueryDone) > 0) {
                        qPtr = qQueryDone + 1
                        startloop()
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                }
            });
        }
```

And of course right below above, the gauge setup code:

```
        window.onload = function () {

            gauge0 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge0",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                label: "Query Time",
                showInnerShadow: true,
                shadowOpacity: 2,
                shadowSize: 5,
                donut: true,
                counter:false,
                decimals:2,
                levelColors: [
                    "#00fff6",
                    "#ff00fc",
                    "#1200ff"
                ]
            });

            gauge1 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge1",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                label: "Query Count",
                showInnerShadow: true,
                shadowOpacity: 2,
                shadowSize: 5,
                donut: true,
                refreshAnimationType: "bounce",
                startAnimationType: ">",
                counter: true
            });
        }
```

so, now when we run, we get see this:

[image]